# Why did I fail to build boost from source?

Tags: centos, c++, build, autotools

This issue is not the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7644205/is-it-possible-to-have-an-unrelated-autotools-project-inside-an-autotools-projec

The error message is as follows:

```
[mirror@hugemeow tmp]$ ./configure
configure: error: cannot run /bin/sh ./config.sub
rm: cannot remove `core': Is a directory
```

Comment: You're probably missing essential information, starting with your CentOS version, what you downloaded exactly and what steps you performed. Also, your question might be better suited for [SO] if it pertains to software tools generally used by programmers such as Boost.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than screwing your system, pay a visit to http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/RebuildSRPM , download the src.rpm for boost from Centos 6 ( if you are on CentOS 5) or from Fedora 17 (if you are on CentOS 6) and rebuild the package.

Comment: i have to install boost to my home directory, so rpm may not work...